# I get 3 errors when I try to run timer

Tags: java, android, error-handling

```
Syntax error on Token "Void", @ expected
run cannot be resolved to a type
Sytax error, insert enumBody to complete BlockStatement!
```

These are 3 errors I get at the below script. What might be problem? Notice that all unneeded stuff probably belongs to my other functions and stuff. I do have all imports too in reality :)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainStuff extends Activity {
    TextView tere;
    TextView dateatm;
    TextView timeatm;
    String nimi;
    String ip;
    protected static final int REFRESH = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        // Refresh after 5 sec... //
        Thread refresherAplle = new Thread();
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int refresherApple = 0;
                    while (refresherApple < 5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        refresherApple = refresherApple + 100;
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.REFRESHER"));
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Thread definition is incorrect. The semi-colon at the end terminates the statement.

Do it **like this** instead.

```
Thread refreshAplle = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
     ....
    }
};
```

Currently you have a method inside a method. Thats the reason for all the token exceptions.

Comment: and also he should start the thread : refreshAplle.start();  :)

Comment: Aww, I couldnt decide which one to mark, but since u said "start thread" then you got it :), as I was missing this too :P

Answer (score 2):

It should be `new Thread() {` i.e. an opening curly brace which, when used as `new Class() {`, is the syntax used to create a new [anonymous inner class](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1849) that extends/implements the declared Class (Thread in this case).

At the moment you just create an instance of `Thread()` as you terminate the line with a `;` and therefore the `public void run() { }` is declared in a code block, which is illegal.  To create an anonymous class you use the following syntax:

```
Thread refresherAplle = new Thread() { //< notice this
    public void run() {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kal.  I got the -1 because I marked down an answer when it was wrong (before it got corrected) and Blundell returned the favour.

Answer (score 0):

Your run is in the middle of know were, try this:

```
 Thread refreshAplle = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                  int refresherApple = 0;
                  while (refresherApple < 5000){
                     sleep(100);
                     refresherApple = refresherApple + 100;
                   }
                 startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.REFRESHER"));
             } finally{
                finish();
             }
        }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your thread in brackets

```
Thread refresherApple = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int refresherApple = 0;
                    while (refresherApple < 5000){
                        sleep(100);
                        refresherApple = refresherApple + 100;
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.REFRESHER"));
                }
                finally{
                    finish();
                }
                }
            };
```